# SAS - Find Palindromes for all Datasets in a Directory

Tags: macros, sas, palindrome

### Task:

I need to identify all palindromes within a directory. I use a proc contents and proc sort to identify the datasets within a directory, like so:

```
proc contents data = dPath._all_ out = dFiles (keep = memname);
run; 

proc sort data = dFiles nodupkey; by memname;run;
```

I want to identify palindromes within this directory.

### Issue:

I plan to use macros because I need to do this for all datasets within a directory. So, instead of the user inputting the string to check if there is a palindrome, I need that to be done dynamically, i.e. identify any palindromes within a dataset.

### Updates:

[image: data_set]
[image: output full row-WANT SPECIFIC ELEMENT]
As you can see in the above pictures, I am able to successfully flag the palindromes for case sensitive and case insensitive situations. I would like to output the specific element that is a palindrome to a separate dataset. Currently, I am only able to output the entire row with the palindrome in it.

### Code:

```
data palindrome_set (drop = i) palindrome_case_sensitive palindrome_case_insensitive;
            set reverse_rows;
                array palindrome[*] _all_ ;
                do i = 1 to dim(palindrome);
                    palindrome_cs = (trim(palindrome[i]) eq reverse(trim(palindrome[i])));
/*                      if palindrome_cs = 1 then output palindrome[i];                                         WANT TO OUTPUT SPECIFIC ELEMENT, NOT ENTIRE ROW*/
                    palindrome_cis = (lowcase(trim(palindrome[i])) eq reverse(lowcase(trim(palindrome[i]))));
                end;
                output palindrome_set;
                if palindrome_cs = 1 then output palindrome_case_sensitive;         *WANT TO OUTPUT SPECIFIC ELEMENT, NOT ENTIRE ROW;
                if palindrome_cis = 1 then output palindrome_case_insensitive;      *WANT TO OUTPUT SPECIFIC ELEMENT, NOT ENTIRE ROW;
            run;
```

Comment: You won't be using macro to evaluate the values.  Figure out how to write a data step to determine if a palindromic value occurs in a single column.  You can expand from there and perform the same check against each element in an array of all the character variables `array string_variables _character_;`  Then decide if you want to also check for palindromic numeric values, if so apply the numeric test for each element in `array num_variables _numeric_;`

Comment: Once you process a single data set, macroize the process and have a macro parameter to pass in the data set name.  Then you can invoke the macro for each distinct data set name in the library as obtained from `Proc Contents`, `SASHELP.VTABLE` or Proc SQL `from DICTIONARY.TABLES where libname="your-libref"`

Answer (score 1):

If memtype ="DATA" then the Memname in your code will hold the table names only.
To check palindromes in table names using your code above; try:

```
%macro palindrome (parameter = ); 
%let string = %sysfunc(reverse(%sysfunc(compress("&parameter ",,sp);
%let reverse = %sysfunc(compress(["&parameter ");
%if %upcase(&string.) = %upcase(&reverse.)  %then %do;
ods output = "/palindrome"
%end;

data work.palindromes;
set work.dfiles;
%macro palindrome (parameter = Memname);
run;
```

Comment: @datanalyst Please update your *question* with code you have tried and any problems you encounter.  Hint: Nest trim() inside the reverse() to prevent trailing spaces ending up as leading spaces. `palindrome_flag = (item eq reverse(trim(item)));`

Comment: @Richard thank you for your comments. I have updated my code with the next steps I am trying to achieve. I'm able to identify palindromes, now I am looking to output the specific element in the array palindrome to a seperate dataset that identifies if it is a case sensitive or case insensitive palindrome. Thanks again for your direction.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your image showed a reversal of the variable names as well.

The underlying variable name corresponding to an array reference can be retrieved using the data step function `VNAME()`.  Also, the formatted value of a variable can be obtained using the data step function `VVALUE`.  Both these functions have a dynamic version -- `VNAMEX` and `VVALUEX`.  An array based solution will not need to utilize the `X` versions of the functions.

Processing all variables via an array is a little tricky because you need additional variables to perform the processing, and you don't want those tested for palindromicity.  In this example, worker variable names use the convention of starting with `_pal` in the hopes of avoiding variable name collision with the data sets being processed.  The example processes a single data set, but it should be obvious how to macro-ize the code and have it work for a data set name that is passed.

```
data want(keep=_palds_ _palrow_ _palvar_ _palval_);
  set sashelp.class;

  array _pals_ _character_;  * array elements are those character variables in the pdv at this point in the data step;
  array _palx_ _numeric_;    * array elements are those numeric variables in the pdv at this point in the data step;

  attrib
    _palds_ length  = $42
    _palrow_ length = 8
    _palvar_ length = $32
    _palval_ length = $500
  ;

  * check raw character value;
  do _palindex_ = 1 to dim(_pals_);
    if length (_pals_(_palindex_)) > lengthm(_palval_) then do;
      _palvar_ = vname (_pals_(_palindex_));
      put "NOTE: sashelp.class " _n_= _palVar_ " had a value that is longer than _palval_ container";
      continue;
    end;

    if _pals_(_palindex_) = reverse(trim(_pals_(_palindex_))) then do;
      _palds_ = "sashelp.class";
      _palrow_ = _n_;
      _palvar_ = vname (_pals_(_palindex_));
      _palval_ = _pals_(_palindex_);
    end;
  end;

  * check formatted numeric value;
  do _palindex_ = 1 to dim(_palx_);
    if left(vvalue(_palx_(_palindex_))) = reverse(trim(vvalue(_palx_(_palindex_)))) then do;
      _palds_ = "sashelp.class";
      _palrow_ = _n_;
      _palvar_ = vname (_palx_(_palindex_));
      _palval_ = _palx_(_palindex_);
    end;
  end;
run;
```

A macro that wants to explicitly avoid name collision must perform some navel-gazing on the data set to be processed in order to generate worker variable names that do not collide.

Processing all members of the libref can be very resource intensive if the libref connects to a remote host -- so a robust solution may want skip over those.

Some other approaches:

- use `CALL VNEXT` routine to iterate through the pdv variables
- use the dictionary table or proc contents output as a basis for generating a *wall of variable tests* in a data step that does not rely on arrays.